# Reading response XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, web-services

I want to read below XMLfile with C# LINQ.
I have tried this code in C#. But not able to get address element data.

### CODE:

```
 XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
 XNamespace nsa = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

 var Address = from r in XDocumentdata.Descendants(ns + "Address")
               select new
                     {
                       Locality = r.Element(nsa + "Locality").Value,
                       CountryRegion = r.Element(nsa + "CountryRegion").Value
                     };

 foreach (var r in Address)
 {
     string CountryRegion = r.CountryRegion;
     string Locality = r.Locality;
 }
```

### XML:

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>Copyright © 2015 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright>


    <BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri>
      <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
      <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
      <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
      <TraceId>1cf1896a29234bc583b75487b57e343f|HK20271655|02.00.163.1200|HK2SCH010280821, i-d219511f.ap-southeast-1b</TraceId>
      <ResourceSets>
        <ResourceSet>
          <EstimatedTotal>5</EstimatedTotal>
          <Resources>
            <Location>
              <Name>Panjagutta, Hyderabad 500082, India</Name>
              <Point>
                <Latitude>17.4176132</Latitude>
                <Longitude>78.449595</Longitude>
              </Point>
              <BoundingBox>
                <SouthLatitude>17.41759</SouthLatitude>
                <WestLongitude>78.44907</WestLongitude>
                <NorthLatitude>17.41764</NorthLatitude>
                <EastLongitude>78.4502</EastLongitude>
              </BoundingBox>
              <EntityType>Address</EntityType>
              <Address>
                <AddressLine>Panjagutta</AddressLine>
                <AdminDistrict>TS</AdminDistrict>
                <AdminDistrict2>Hyderabad</AdminDistrict2>
                <CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion>
                <FormattedAddress>Panjagutta, Hyderabad 500082, India</FormattedAddress>
                <Locality>Hyderabad</Locality>
                <PostalCode>500082</PostalCode>
              </Address>
              <Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
              <MatchCode>Good</MatchCode>
              <GeocodePoint>
                <Latitude>17.4176132</Latitude>
                <Longitude>78.449595</Longitude>
                <CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod>
                <UsageType>Display</UsageType>
                <UsageType>Route</UsageType>
              </GeocodePoint>
            </Location>

          </Resources>
        </ResourceSet>
      </ResourceSets>
    </Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong namespace. The root namespace for the document, denoted by an unaliased `xmlns` attribute for the XML document is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1`.

Use that rather than the current value of `nsa`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class / model that matches the structure of XML and
   deserializes XML into an object or collection.
2. Use Linq to work with collection if you need.

And look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("your xml path");
var address = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Address");
```

I can access the elements inside the Address element Now.